# Rebuild accidentally deleted /dev

Tags: 10.04, devices, udev

How to rebuild `/dev/` on an Ubuntu lucid where everything in `/dev/` were accidentally deleted?

`MAKEDEV std` and `MAKEDEV pty` aren't enough, which isn't surprising on a system using `udev`.

I haven't rebooted yet because I fear I would lose access to my system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the contents of `/dev` are automatically rebuilt when you reboot.

To quote [someone else](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/need-to-rebuild-dev-354950/):

> When you start the system, the "udev" facility examines the hardware configuration (according to established rules) and dynamically creates the entries in /dev.

Answer (score 4):

When rebooting is NOT an option (you are working remotely on a machine in usa and you are on safari) this should do the trick:

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
udevadm trigger
```

Comment: +1, because rebooting is for adding new hardware

Comment: Does not work - creates only directories block char disk dri, but not all files that were there

Answer (score 0):

/dev is on a RAM disk so it gets destroyed and recreated on any reboot